# Xcode : build two apps in same target (with the same plist)

Tags: ios, xcode, build, target, ipa

Now I have 3 targets in my iOS application so I build 3 apps (3 ipa).
But I want to keep only 3 target but I want to generate 6 apps (6 ipa).

On each target I want to create an app and a pilot app.
I really want to keep only 1 plist for app and pilot app.
Only differences with app and pilot app are :

- Bundle identifier (to install these two apps on the same device)
- Icon application
- 1 parameter in plist
- Few line in code (changing with #IF PILOT add code #ENDIF

It's important to keep the same plist for each target (a target is equivalent to en environment TEST, INT and PROD). Because if I duplicate my target in two target (PROD and PROD PILOT for example) it will be more difficult to maintain thes application because if a day I want to change something in plist I will do the same in PILOT target plist.
So you understand it can create differences if I forget to dusplicate my changements.

Finally it will be great if I can build the app and the pilot app just in 1 build and generate 2 Archives in one time also.

Is it possible ?
And have you ideas for the realisation ?

Me I have just fews ideas like :

- Add arguments in my target
- Add user defined setting
- Add preprocessing macros

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under your project settings, for each target, look under build settings -> packaging, try set all the info.plist files to point to the same one instead of their own versions.

Answer (score 0):

If it is testing purpose, 
Try changing Bundle identifier in Project settings and change Product Name in build settings and take archive files.
It will be deployed as separate app in device.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fonix !

My solution use your advice.
I duplicated my 3 targets but an app target and its pilot version are linked to the same plist file.
Moreover, I had a preprocessor macro "PILOTE=1" in each pilote version.
Finally I declare a string in user-defined to define my icon ("ICON -> icon.png or icon-pilote.png) and I declare in CFBundleIcon item0 -> ${ICON}).

And to add part of code I juste declare the code difference in :

#IFDEF PILOTE

//Code Pilot version

#ELSE

//Code standard version

#ENDIF

Is it a nice choice for my needs ?